# Automation Anywhere community edition in azure cloud

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-automation, rpa, automationanywhere

I would like to know whether *Automation Anywhere Community Edition* can install in *Azure cloud as a Paas (Platform as a service)*?. If yes, please let me know the details.

Comment: What is the Automation Anywhere Community Edition? Could you provide some links?

Comment: @NancyXiong Its a RPA tool and this is the site: https://www.automationanywhere.com/products/community-edition for community edition

Comment: When you search Automation Anywhere in the [Azure marketplace](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/automationanywhere.automationexpress?tab=Overview), you only could find the Enterprise version

Comment: @NancyXiong : Thanks for the reply, and I need to know how AA as PAAS.